# How to change the class to a hyperlink a href

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to change the CSS for the a href tag.
I have been doing this in the tag directly like the following:

```
<a style="color: #1474c8; margin-bottom: 20px" href="#">This is link #1 </a>
```

This is working prefect, but I have to do several links so I consider this isn't the best way to do it. So I created a CSS class, but it's not working the same. Each time I pass the mouse over the link it behaves as a normal hyper link with the default href CSS. If I click in the link it change of color. So not sure what I'm missing

```
.parentCat_wChildren{
  color: #1474c8;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.parentCat_wChildren a:link{ color: #1474c8; text-decoration: none;}
.parentCat_wChildren a:visited { color: #1474c8; text-decoration: none;}
.parentCat_wChildren a:hover { color: #1474c8; text-decoration: none;}
.parentCat_wChildren a:active { color: #1474c8; text-decoration: none;}

<a class="parentCat_wChildren" href="#">This is link #2.1</a>
```

Adding a JSBin: https://output.jsbin.com/vutozicato

Comment: `.parentCat_wChildren a` This says "find an element with the class parentCat_wChildren and then inside that element look for an <a> tag". This does not match your HTML structure. Also note, if you have many classes that all have the same styling you can comma separate the selectors instead of writing the style over and over like you have.

Comment: use `.parentCat_wChildren:link`, `.parentCat_wChildren:visited`, etc...

Comment: Think I got , wondering why the negative vote :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.parentCat_wChildren` **is already an `a` anchor** so use:

```
.parentCat_wChildren:link {
```

or eventually:

```
a.parentCat_wChildren:link { /*make suer to also use  a.parentCat_wChildren{ in this case*/
```

but **not**  `.parentCat_wChildren a:link {`

---

P.S: 
You can define `text-decoration: none;` only in one place, inside your first `.parentCat_wChildren{` statement.